# Is it possible to get the server ip from client device with javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'd like to know the exact server ip that we are trying to connect and the dns responses with javascript in client devices.(not client's ip)
I've been reading some articles, and so far the result is unavailable, but I still wonder if there's any Big man who's able to figure it out.

For example:
I would to execute the behavior "ping" to get the server ip.
But in javascript, it seems unavailable.

> ping google.com
> PING google.com (xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq): 56 data bytes

Comment: Thank you for all the answers below. After checking the available function and internet protocols, we can't just get the server ip with simple client devices. So don't promise to do this service from your boss or pms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not that I am aware of.** 
Though, this will get the hostname

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ip = location.host;
  alert(ip);
</script>
```

I understand you requested for a JS solution, but here is a PHP solution that will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ip = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>";
  alert(ip);
</script>`
```

Otherwise, I am pretty sure that there is no a sure-fire way to do this. You can request to an external source that will do it for you.

**Or**

This will enable you to ping the server. Unfortunately, you will need to provide the IP.
https://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

Comment: Thank you, Aspect. It helps me from having to do this.